# What does Chuwa mean?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, eve

> And Adam knew **Eve** his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and
> said, I have gotten a man from the Lord. Gen 4:1

Alive/life = חי (chai).
.... = חוה (chuwa) ?

Answer (score 3):

Hawwah, is literally "a living being,"
[image]

Comment: Thanks.........

Comment: A common suggestion is that hawwa means “life” or “living” or “life giver,”

Comment: Please elaborate and provide sources.

Answer (score 2):

Genesis 3:20
New International Version

> Adam named his wife **Eve**, because she would become the mother of all the **living**.

https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2332.htm
Brown-Driver-Briggs

> I. חַוָּה proper name, feminine (*life*,

The name *Eve* means *life*.